# JPA table column of type enum

Tags: database, jpa, enums

I have a table column of type enum (mycoloumn enum('HIGH','LOW'))
How do I map in my model java class? using JPA annotation. I am using MySQL database.

thanks, for help.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, using JDBC, you would use `setString()` / `getString()` to access such a column. So you should probably map it as a corresponding Java enum, using its name:

```
public enum Volume { 
    HIGH, LOW
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Volume volume;
```